# React TS error using Types missing propeties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a filter system and run into a problem.
I set a few types:

```
type Brand = {
    brand:string;
    checked:boolean;
}
type Gender = {
    gender: "Male" | "Female" | "Kids";
    checked:boolean;
}
type Shoes = {
    brand:Brand;
    gender:Gender;
}
```

and then i'm trying to create a useState object like this:

```
const [filterState,setFilterState] = useState<Shoes>({
        brand:[
            {
                brand:'New Balance',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Nike',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Addiddas',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Puma',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Converse',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Under Armour',
                checked: false,
            },
        ],
        gender:[{
            gender:'Male',
            checked:false,
        },
        {
            gender:'Female',
            checked:false,
        },
        {
            gender:'Kids',
            checked:false,
        }
    ],
    });
```

However on the key brand and gender i'm getting this type of error:

```
Type '{ brand: string; checked: false; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Brand': brand, checked
```

even though i'm adding all the type properties. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that your `brand` property and your `gender` property are arrays:

```
type Shoes = {
    brand: Brand[]; // or Array<Brand>
    gender: Gender[]; // or Array<Gender>
}
```

Probably better to name your properties `brands` and `genders` though.

Comment: Gender too, by the looks. Also an array.